# PYbluez2 : Unable to scan the devices [ devices.discover]

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

```
import bluetooth as bt



nearby_devices = bt.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print("Found {} devices.".format(len(nearby_devices)))

x = int(1)
bluetooth_devices = []
for addr, name in nearby_devices:
     new_device = ("{} - Address: {} - Name: {}").format(x, addr, name)
     bluetooth_devices.append(new_device)
     x += 1
```

Hi,
I am trying to scan the available devices and print them out using pybluez2 but I am not got any success so far. However, there is no error either as It just print :  0 device available

Here is the code i am using:

I want to scan and print the available devices
and i am using pybluez2 as pybluez is throwing some error
which I was unable to solve so far.